# Do I need to publish my application on google playstore in order to integrate Unity Ads?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase, ads, unityads

Do I have to publish my application on google playstore in order to integrate Unity Ads and earn revenue? or can I publish it in other platforms and get revenue as well. without google playstore?

Answer (score 2):

Unity Ads support only these two platforms: IOS (Appstore) and Android (Google Play)
You can still implement Unity Ads for other Android platforms such as Amazon and Huawei App stores, but Unity Ads campaings advertise apps on Google Play so they will need Play store for it [read more here](https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000117543-What-platforms-does-Unity-Ads-support-)